# Can I configure LLBLGen to include generated SQL in exceptions?

Tags: llblgenpro, llblgen

I'm using LLBLGen and I have some code like so:

```
    if (onlyRecentMessages)
    {
        messageBucket.PredicateExpression.Add(MessageFields.DateEffective >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30));
    }

    var messageEntities = new EntityCollection<MessageEntity>();
    using (var myAdapter = PersistenceLayer.GetDataAccessAdapter())
    {
        myAdapter.FetchEntityCollection(messageEntities, messageBucket);
    }
```

I'm currently getting a SqlException on the FetchEntityCollection line.  The error is:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.

but that's a side note.  What I actually want to be able to do is include the generated SQL in a custom exception in my code.  So for instance something like this:

```
 using (var myAdapter = PersistenceLayer.GetDataAccessAdapter())
        {
            try
            {
               myAdapter.FetchEntityCollection(messageEntities, messageBucket);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
               throw new CustomSqlException(ex, myAdapter.GeneratedSqlFromLastOperation);
            }
        }
```

Of course, there is no such property as GeneratedSqlFromLastOperation.  I'm aware that I can configure logging, but I would prefer to have the information directly in my stack track / exception so that my existing exception logging infrastructure can provide me with more information when these kinds of errors occur.

Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get an ORMQueryExecutionException, which contains the full query in the description. The query's execute method wraps all exceptions in an ORMQueryExecutionException and stores the query in the description.

ps: please, if possible ask llblgen pro related questions on our forums, as we don't monitor stackoverflow frequently. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess now my task is to try and get ELMAH to do something with that description, or else to do some custom exception handling that refers to it.

Comment: Oh, and I do end up searching llblgen.com/tinyforum but honestly to ask questions I find SO to be a nicer interface and I don't have to remember one more login.